# In bloc management how to update a usermodel emitted by a bloc state?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I have a usermodel class which stores say, username and email. On login attempt, it will query my database (Im using sql through coldfusion API, I think it works so far), check if the credentials is correct, and return data of the user to be copied into the usermodel. The model will then be emitted by my bloc state.

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  AuthBloc() : super(AuthInitial()) {
    final UserProvider userProvider = UserProvider();

    on<LoggedIn>((event, emit) async {
      try {
        final correctCredentials = await userProvider.checkLoginCredentials(
            event.username, event.password);
        if (correctCredentials) {
          final model = await userProvider.getSpecificUserData(event.username);
          emit(Authenticated(model));
        } else {
          emit(AuthFailedCredentials());
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print("Server error");
        print(e);
        emit(AuthFailedServer());
      }
    });

    on<Relog>((event, emit) async {
      print("authbloc relog");
      emit(Authenticated(event.usermodel));
    });
```

my states

```
part of 'auth_bloc.dart';

abstract class AuthState extends Equatable {
  const AuthState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class AuthInitial extends AuthState {}

class Unauthenticated extends AuthState {}

class AuthFailedCredentials extends AuthState {}

class AuthFailedServer extends AuthState {}

class Authenticated extends AuthState {
  final UserModel model;
  const Authenticated(this.model);
}
```

my app will then build depending on the state

```
return Scaffold(
      body: BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is AuthInitial) {
            print("state is initial");
            return const SplashPage();
          } else if (state is Authenticated) {
            print("state is auth");
            return const HomePage();
          } else if (state is AuthFailedCredentials) {
            context.read<AuthBloc>().add(SignIn());
            popUpDialog(
                context, "Log Masuk Gagal", "Salah kata nama/kata laluan");
            return Container();
          } else if (state is AuthFailedServer) {
            context.read<AuthBloc>().add(SignIn());
            popUpDialog(context, "Log Masuk Gagal", "Masalah Server/Internet");
            return Container();
          } else {
            print("state is unauthenticated");
            return const LoginScreen();
          }
```

So far so good, I can create a profile page which display the users data by accessing the emitted model by `UserModel currentUserModel = (authbloc.state as Authenticated).model; avatarUrl = currentUserModel.avatar ?? '';`

But the problem is when I want to update said model when user want to edit their data. I managed to send request http to update the users data and it does change the data in sql, but since my app only queried the database at login earlier, it didnt detect the changes until I relog.

Sample of how I change part of the users data in the server (Sql), I know it works because the data does change in my sqlyog table. So currently, data in db updates but not the current one emitted by state for the whole app.

```
  Future<String> updateSignature(UserModel usermodel, Uint8List data) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'http://192.168.1.166:8500/rest/isewa/isewarestpath/updateSignature');

    final signatureString = _encodeBase64(data);

    final requestBody = {
      "Method": "PUT",
      "GateWayName": "users",
      "Attributes": {
        "Value": {"username": usermodel.username, "signature": signatureString}
      }
    };
    try {
      final response = await http.put(
        url,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: json.encode(requestBody),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print('repo/updateSignature/success');
        final data = json.decode(response.body);
        if (data['Status']['success']) {
          return 'true';
        } else {
          print('repo/updateSignature/notsuccess');
          print(data['Status']['message']);
          return data['Status']['message'];
        }
      } else {
        print('repo/updateSignature/statuscode != 200');
        throw Exception(response.statusCode);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e);
    }
  }
```

Whats a good approach to solve this?

Instead of model, I tried to emit username instead, and at each page it will query the API to get usermodel based on the username. But this becomes v cumbersome since theres many page, and actually didnt get it to work since my page was built before it finish querying (I think?) cuz it displayed the default name instead of actual user's username. Maybe its jz bad coding in my part, but was wondering if theres better approach to tackle this.

Comment: what do you mean:
'I managed to send request http to update the users data and it does change the data in sql' - where and hou you do it?
'didnt detect the changes until I relog'  - where and hou you do trying to detect it?

Comment: hi, i added more info on how i update the data in the sql. The how to detect is the problem currently, Idk how to make the app requery on server db changes.

Answer (score 1):

in this case after you call

```
await updateSignature(..)
```

you shoud notify AuthBloc by pass new event like RefreshAuthEvent:

```
BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context).add(RefreshAuthEvent);
```

and handle it to emit new Authenticated state with updated data:

```
on<RefreshAuthEvent>((event, emit) async {
do query and update data to emit new updated state...
```

more info in [docs](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=blocprovider)

Comment: but since im using BlocBuilder, wont a change in state triggers it, for example using my current blocbuilder, it will redirect to LoginScreen(). Is there a way to make it so ill remain at whatever page i am when calling the RefreshAuthEvent?

Comment: if I understand correctly, on RefreshAuthEvent you could emit Authenticated with updated data, so you will ramain in HomeScreen.

Comment: Yes it did, it slipped my mind I can still emit the same state from different event, I was originally thinking I need a new state. However for some reason my blocbuilder didnt react even when I call add.LoggedIn() after updating data (it works when user first logs in though), so I had to create a new event Relog (I added the code to original post) to reemit the state.

Comment: For some reason though, if I code the Relog like how I did my LoggedIn ie. pass username to Relog, query database to get model, emit Auth(model), the blocBuilder does not react. So instead I had to query for model before calling the event and passing it the model so it can straight away emit Auth(model), and in this case, yes the blocBuilder react and rebuilt the homepage. I dont mind this workaround, but just wondering why it happens?

Comment: please, provide all of yours states.